# iPad App orientation changes background flashes white

Tags: ios, adobe-dps

I am working in InDesign DPS to create an iPad book and have options for both portrait and landscape views. Everything is working correctly except when I change the orientation of the iPad between portrait and landscape there is a white background that "flashes" briefly in the non-content area at the bottom of the screen until the destination orientation fills the screen.

How do I eliminate that irritant?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it your window ?

Change it's background color to black in your `didFinishLaunch...` : `self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];`

Comment: Hi Templar, that would work if I was working in Xcode, but I am doing this in InDesign DPS.